# Help us with a little clean up!

Tags: support, moderation, deleted-questions

I went ahead and deleted a bunch of questions which were either closed, downvoted and unsalvageable or were closed, with no answer and abandoned since 2012.

Please review my work by going through and flagging obvious mistakes -- if you find a good question that needs epic edits, please ask it again properly instead of flagging.

You can remove question links from the answers below once you've done.

WARNING: This is not great content, you might find the experience ...depressing.

Also: you obviously need a [high enough rep](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) (>10,000 reputation points) or be the owner to see these posts!

Comment: [One of the questions deleted seems to be a duplicate](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14516/is-fluoridated-water-toxic-do-i-have-the-right-to-reject-it). Is it a site policy to delete duplicates? (or it was deleted due to being really sucky independent of being a dupe?)

Comment: Also, some should be migrated instead of being deleted. E.g. [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/why-nobody-ever-attack-switzerland) or [this](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17016/great-wall-of-china-loopholes) may be worth asking on History.SE. How does that tally with the high level policy?

Comment: @DVK: Normally duplicates are left, to help future searchers get to the right question. In this case, it seems to be the -10 votes that got it deleted.

Answer (score 2):

## Closed, unanswered and abandoned since 2012

- [Why are we able to see objects that are several light years away, but we've been unable to determine if there is one in our celestial backyard?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/826)
- [Is anything known about the origin of the "Tomato Man" alien body hoax?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/2261)
- [Is there any proof, enhanced airport security in US has significantly reduced terror attacks in US plane?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7100)
- [Can someone keep a razor blade in his mouth without injury?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/7299)
- [Does gaming increase productivty?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8184)
- [Is a cold shower good for you? (Less hair loss, better health, refreshing, etc.?)](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8291)
- [Could a global nuclear war damage planet earth structurally in a significant way?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8294)
- [Is the viral video KONY 2012 Legit?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8362)
- [Do colours affect consumer behaviour?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8404)
- [Does lumosity.com help one improve his/hers brain activity or not](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8412)
- [Where is Joseph Kony?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8481)
- [Are radiator reflectors as effective as claimed?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8665)
- [Can a significant human population be started with only one couple?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8728)
- [If you fall onto the subway tracks, is this the best way to survive?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13933)
- [Can the EmDrive produce thrust for a spacecraft without propellant?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13543)
- [Can a human survive on Mars in a neoprene diving suit?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/11053)
- [Are "undecided voters" truly undecided?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10762)
- [Has content from Wikileaks led to direct harm (as of Aug 2012)?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10560)
- [Will the internet survive a major (nuclear) war, between regional or global powers?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10483)
- [Did Erwin König Exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10474)
- [Does the color magenta exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10370)
- [Which publishers provide reference for scientific topics and latest research in a handbook format?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10358)
- [Have armed bystanders ever stopped a shooting rampage](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10348)
- [Does this secret online blackmarket weapons store exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10201)
- [Why is North Korea the only country not mapped by Google?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/10035)
- [Can the Cochrane reviews be regarded as a definitive source of information?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9918)
- [Was the average life expectancy of a US soldier in Vietnam 15 minutes?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9738)
- [How dangerous is it to be in a small watercraft when thunder is heard?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9674)
- [Can advertisers legally hire actors who have never used a product to say they have used it and gotten specific results from it?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9605)
- [Is EuroZone on the verge of a financial crisis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9592)
- [Is brushing your teeth in the kitchen sink anti-hygienic?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9591)
- [Do double jeopardy laws allow you to freely commit a crime if you have already been found guilty for the same crime previously?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9576)
- [Are many or most people reluctant to trust shortened URLs?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9439)
- [To what degree is applied quantum mechanics used in the design and fabrication of semiconductor chips?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9375)
- [Does "Where the Wild Things Are" frighten children to a degree that author Maurice Sendak failed to comprehend?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9372)
- [Is there evidence that you feel more tired two days after getting little sleep?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9185)
- [Will super intelligent machines arise to build still smarter machines?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9163)
- [Meat and gaining weight](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9159)
- [Do we need to eat our greens?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9130)
- [Do Wiccan energy balls exist?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9091)
- [Should diabetics worry about sugar or about calories?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8940)
- [Is owning a handgun for personal protection justifiable under risk analysis?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8926)

Answer (score 1):

### Closed, downvoted and unsalvageable

- [Is fluoridated water toxic? Do I have the right to reject it?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14516)
- [Why doesn't the high amount of fluoride found in tea or tobacco prevent dental caries? Or does it have to be hydrofluorosilicic acid?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14227)
- [Does Deutronomy 22:13-21 say that non-virgin wives will be executed?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16758)
- [Why nobody ever attack Switzerland?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16243)
- [Do fire-eaters eat fire?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16074)
- [Can a woman get pregnant after only one instance of intercourse?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/22363)
- [Is Newton's first law not true beyond the edge of our universe?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/20673)
- [Is the U.S. the most technologically advanced country in the world?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17173)
- [Are 50% of adults in Rhode Island functionally illiterate?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16585)
- [Does this picture have financial credibility?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/23285)
- [Great Wall of China loopholes](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17016)
- [Probabilistic approach to the validity of evolution](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/17627)
- [Should you speed up driving over a pothole?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14313)
- [If something happens "on the internet", in which country does it happen?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16963)
- [Do powerline network adapters emit electromagnetic radiation when not paired?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14708)
- [Does human water consumption have an environmental impact?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/13963)
- [Does saliva cause tooth decay?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/16263)
- [Could dental fluorosis and incipient dental caries (cavities) be the same thing?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/14330)
- [Is GDP a flawed measure of progress?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/26931)
- [is there any specific reason behind the shape of single use plastic water bottles](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/23158)
- [What does "more likely to be disbelievers" mean in this article?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/9135)
- [Can economics of large-scale societal change be accurately predicted?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/8907)
- [copper bracelets and the affects of shocks](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/27562)

Answer (score 1):

Some questions should be strongly **considered** for migration, assuming target site mods are willing to take some of them.

I'm almost certain that some of them are downvoted and abandoned due to mis-fit with Skeptics model (lack of notable claim) and **not due to innate poor quality**.

Some of these are for new sites, possibly post-dating the question's closure.

---

Biology.SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8728/can-a-significant-human-population-be-started-with-only-one-couple (Frankly, given the latter edits, it seems to be a pretty good fit even here but i don't feel like arguing that one)

---

Meta.Skeptics.SE

- <del>https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9918/can-the-cochrane-reviews-be-regarded-as-a-definitive-source-of-information</del> done

---

Futrure law.SE:

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9576/do-double-jeopardy-laws-allow-you-to-freely-commit-a-crime-if-you-have-already-b
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16963/if-something-happens-on-the-internet-in-which-country-does-it-happen: politics.SE or better yet Law.SE if it ever gets to private beta

---

Economics.SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9592/is-eurozone-on-the-verge-of-a-financial-crisis (though this one is dated to the point it may be meaningless to ask)

---

History.SE:

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/16243/why-nobody-ever-attack-switzerland
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17016/great-wall-of-china-loopholes
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/9738/was-the-average-life-expectancy-of-a-us-soldier-in-vietnam-15-minutes

---

Earth Sciences SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/13963/does-human-water-consumption-have-an-environmental-impact (though it may be too low quality?)

---

Politics.SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8926/is-owning-a-handgun-for-personal-protection-justifiable-under-risk-analysis (may needs some polishing)
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10762/are-undecided-voters-truly-undecided

---

Astronomy.SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/826/why-are-we-able-to-see-objects-that-are-several-light-years-away-but-weve-been

---

UX.SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/23158/is-there-any-specific-reason-behind-the-shape-of-single-use-plastic-water-bottle
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8404/do-colours-affect-consumer-behaviour (though it may need tightening up to be worth migrating, see comments)

---

Worldbuilding.SE

- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8294/could-a-global-nuclear-war-damage-planet-earth-structurally-in-a-significant-way  (could also be ontopic on Physics?)

Comment: Migrating closed/downvoted/abandoned questions is probably not what we should do: instead of migrating, these questions should be reopened where appropriate, if anyone is interested in adapting them to the other sites and eventually accepting a good answer.

Comment: @Sklivvz - I'm almost certain that some of them are downvoted and abandoned due to misfit with Skeptics model (lack of notable claim) and not innate poor quality. The Switzerland is definitely a good one and wouldn't be downvoted on History, I'm sure. Ditto the first one - it's very poor as a Skeptics question but pretty interesting from politics/jurisdiction angle. Plus, as I said, it's up to target site moderators :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/131112 also, some of them might be closed because they were bounced by the migration target (I haven't checked).

Comment: @Sklivvz - And? As I said, I'm very explicitly claiming (unless otherwise caveated in accompanying text) that some of the questions are **not** crap, they are just poor fit for Skeptics while being good fit for larger SE.

Comment: The title of the question I linked is "Why was this question closed as off-topic without being migrated?". We generally already migrate away all that is suitable/wanted by the target sites.

Comment: Don't get me wrong though, your input is very valuable! It's just that I'd rather have our users get the rep points for salvaging topics than the original authors that abandoned their questions.

Comment: @Sklivvz - Are you claiming that the specific questions I listed have already been reviewd and judged unsuitable by a target site I listed? Or that in your personal experience as a moderator these specific ones are? I suspect these specific ones were never considered for migration.

Comment: @Sklivvz - All I care is getting good answers to questions whose topics sound interesting and which seem answerable by SE
 :)

Comment: I don't remember each one of them: however we do try to migrate stuff out if possible. When this doesn't happen can be for multiple reasons (the other site didn't want it, the question is very low quality, an appropriate site didn't exist, there are already answers, etc.)

Comment: @Sklivvz - well, Earth Sciences may have not existed. IMHO these are worth re-reviewing, not many of them.

Comment: *Dixi*.........

Comment: @DVK: Dixi? Lost you there.

Comment: @oddth Latin. Means I'm done speaking... as in no more questions left to look at from the list: that was the last edit :)

Answer (score 0):

- [This](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/17627/probabilistic-approach-to-the-validity-of-evolution) seems to be based on a pretty frequent creationist claim. Someone should add a cite to the claim, so we can properly answer.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/8412/does-lumosity-com-help-one-improve-his-hers-brain-activity-or-not This seems salvageable, though whether it's worth salvaging is debatable.
- https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/is-anything-known-about-the-origin-of-the-tomato-man-alien-body-hoax

  Should be reopend. I have no idea why this was closed. Seems excactly the kind of claim that's ontopic here - alien claim, and notable.